# what is proper method to create function with parameter and return value in single line?

Tags: typescript1.5, arrow-functions

I am new is ES6 and typescript. Trying to create function that accepts  parameter as array and want to return its length as follows :

```
getSize = (friendsList : Friends[]) => friendsList.length ;
```

But it returns following error :

```
logger:17 TypeScript ';' expected. (TS1005)
logger:17 TypeScript Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. (TS1068)
(index):20 Error: Error: TypeScript transpilation failed(…)
```

Comment: `getSize = (friendsList) => friendsList.length;` does work in ES6, there's only a Typescript problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think may be you want to need is as below:

```
let getSize = (friendsList: Array<number>) => friendsList.length ;
        console.log(getSize([1, 2, 3]));
```

So getSize is now a ***function*** and you can test it with above code.

I have tested above code.

Please test and let me know if it works for your scenario and any other help needed.